# Python PEP3101: Why the field_spec is not passed to the __format__ function?

Tags: python, string, formatting

[PEP 3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) specifies **Advanced String Formatting**. Among other things, it defines a specification of a new syntax for format strings (eg. `{:.2f}`) and how custom types can control their own formatting. This is done by implementing:

```
def __format__(value, format_spec):
     # Your code here
```

The string formatting code can include a conversion flag. For example: `"{0!r:20}".format("Hello")`, where `!r` means `convert the the value to a string using repr()`. However, `__format__` only gets the value after the colon `:` (i.e. the format_spec). I would like to know is the reason (i.e. the design decision, not the code) why? I think that providing everything after the the `!` will be more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part before the colon is only used in string formatting, and is a templating function, *not* about formatting the actual values themselves.

The part *after* the colon is handled separately, and can also be specified using the [`format()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format):

```
>>> format(234, '02x')
'ea'
```

formats the number as lower-cased zero-padded hexadecimal of minimal 2 characters. It is this functionality that `.__format__()` lets you hook into; this is the business end of formatting the value.

The part before the colon specifies the `field_name`, how the string formatter retrieves a value to format. When formatting the value, it shouldn't matter at all how the field was determined. The `field_name` is only useful to locate the value on which to call `.__format__()`, and to specify an alternate conversion method (`!r` or `!s`) for that value.

Note that by using `!r` the `.__format__()` method is **ignored** and `.__repr__()` is used instead! The same applies to `!s` and `.__str__()`:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __repr__(self): return '<Foo repr>'
...     def __str__(self): return 'Foo as string'
...     def __format__(self, spec): return 'Formatting Foo as {}'.format(spec)
... 
>>> '{:02x}'.format(Foo())
'Formatting Foo as 02x'
>>> '{!s}'.format(Foo())
'Foo as string'
>>> '{!r}'.format(Foo())
'<Foo repr>'
```

Comment: But is kind of a waste, because you could define other ways of representing your data in a cleaner way if `__format__` was used for both parts. Now you need to put everything in the spec. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What would you *do* with the part before the `:`? You'd know the name of the keyword parameter, or the index into the positional parameters, plus perhaps the attribute access used. That has nothing to do with formatting!

Comment: Before the `:` the only thing you have is the field name and the conversion switch (so `!r` or `!s`); the latter, if specified, causes the `.__format__()` method to be **ignored**, so there is no point in passing that to the `.__format__()` method..

Comment: For example, you could define `H` to show the object as HTML. I understand that you can do it **after** the `:`, but I think that it makes more sense **before** because is not formatting but a different way of expressing the content.

Comment: Everything before the `:` is about retrieving the value and determining what method to use; `!s` and `!r` are *overrides*. If you want your value to format itself differently for the context, then that is *definitely* about formatting and should be specified after he colon.